# using regex predefined class with an exception in R

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

So I am trying to split my string based on all the punctuations and space wherever they occur in the string (hence the + sign) except for on "#" & "/" because I don't want it to split #n/a which it does. I did search a lot on this problem but can't get to the solution. Any suggestions?

```
t<-"[[:punct:][:space:]]+" 
bh <- tolower(strsplit(as.character(a), t)[[1]])
```

I have also tried storing the following to t but it also gives error

```
t<-"[!"\$%&'()*+,\-.:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~\\ ]+"
```

Error: unexpected input in "t<-"[!"\"

One alternate is to substitute #n/a but I want to know how to do it without having to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex with a lookahead that will restrict the bracket expression pattern:

```
t <- "(?:(?![#/])[[:punct:][:space:]])+"
bh <- tolower(strsplit(as.character(a), t, perl=TRUE)[[1]])
```

The `(?:(?![#/])[[:punct:][:space:]])+` pattern matches 1 or more repetitions of any punctuation or whitespace that is not `#` and `/` chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdbrLE/1).

If you want to spell out the symbols you want to match inside a bracket expression you may fix your other pattern like

```
t <- "[][!\"$%&'()*+,.:;<=>?@\\\\^_`{|}~ -]+"
```

Note that `]` must be right after the opening `[`, `[` inside the expression does not need to be escaped, `-` can be put unescaped at the end, a `\` should be defined with 4 backslashes. `$` does not have to be escaped.